# In need of hints for a couple of measure theoretic exercises:

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would really appreciate some small hints for the following questions:

1. Suppose $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$
   is a measure space such that $\mu\left(X\right)=1$
   and $f,g\in L^{1}\left(X,\mu\right)$
   are functions such that $0<f,g$
   and $f\cdot g\geq1$
   almost surely show that  $\int\limits _{X}fd\mu\cdot\int\limits _{X}gd\mu\geq1$
2. Given $t\in\mathbb{R}$
   and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
   define $f_{t}\left(x\right)=f\left(x+t\right)$
   for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove or bring a counterexample: Given $f\in L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ the mapping $t\mapsto f_{t}$
   is continuous from $\mathbb{R}$
   to $L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$
   .Given $ f\in L^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)
    $ the mapping $t\mapsto f_{t}$
   is continuous from $\mathbb{R}$
   to $L^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$

Some pointers would really help. Regarding the second question I have a feeling that the first case is true and the latter isn't. I tried to dabble a bit with inequalities for the first case but ran into a dead end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.**

*Question 1.* Use Schwartz inequality $\left(\int_X f \,d\mu\right)\left(\int_X g \,d\mu\right)\ge\int_X \sqrt{fg}\,d\mu$.

*Question 2.* In the case of $L^1$ the mapping $t\mapsto f_t$ is continuous, while in the case of $L^\infty$ it is not. For $L^1$, use the fact the the continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

First of all, $\int_{\mathbb R}|f|\,dx=\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{-M}^M|f|\,dx$, and thus for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M>0$, such that $\int_{|x|>M}|f|\,dx<\varepsilon$. Then,$f|_{[-M,M]}$ is $L^1$-approximated by simple functions, i.e. $f\approx\sum_{k=1}^N c_k\chi_{E_k}$, where $\chi_E$ is the characteristic on $E$, and $E_1,\ldots,E_N$ are intervals. Finally, each characteristic of an interval can be $L^1$-approximated by suitable continuous functions.

In the case of $L^\infty$, take $f(x)=\mathrm{sgn}\, x$. Clearly $ \|f_{t+h}-f_t$ $\|_{\infty}=2$, for all $h$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about how to use the density of continuous functions with compact support?

Comment: This elaboration appears in the edited version.